# x86-64 Segfault when calling function (AT&T Syntax)

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

I am new to assembly programming and I am trying to implement a program that asks the user to input two integers. The program should then return the value of the first integer raised to the power of the second integer. I attempt to achieve this by using a loop to multiply the value in RAX over and over again. I believe I have done this correctly but the problem arises when I attempt to call the function pow, resulting in a segmentation fault error. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. The code is below:

```
.text
welcomeStr: .asciz "\nEnter a non-negative base followed by an exponent:\n"
inputStr:   .asciz "%ld"
outputStr:  .asciz "The result is%ld\n"

.data
base:   .quad 0
exp:    .quad 0 

.global main
main:
    # Prologue
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    # Print the welcome message
    movq    $0, %rax
    movq    $welcomeStr, %rdi
    call    printf

    # Get input from user and store in base
    leaq    inputStr(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    base(%rip), %rsi
    call    scanf

    # Get input from user and store in exp
    leaq    inputStr(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    exp(%rip), %rsi
    call    scanf

    call    pow

    # Print the value in rax to the command line
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    movq    $0, %rax
    movq    $outputStr, %rdi
    call    printf

    movq    $0, %rdi
    call    exit

pow:
    # Prologue
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    # Load rcx with the value of the exponential and rax with 1
    movq    exp, %rcx
    movq    $1, %rax

loop:
    cmpq    $0, %rcx
    jle     end # Break loop if the value in rcx is less than or equal to 1
    mulq    base
    dec     %rcx # Decrement counter by one
    jmp     loop # Loop again

    # Epilogue
    movq    %rbp, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Use your debugger to figure out the direct cause of the crash.

Comment: You need to place `main` in the `.text` section.

Comment: Also `scanf` is a varargs function just like `printf` so the same rule of setting `al` to zero applies.

Comment: The direct cause is that you forgot to define your `end` label. Not sure what the linker picks up instead, but definitely not the address you want :)

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you Jester, that was it. The segfault error was making me think that I got the calling convention all wrong. Turns out it was just the undefined label.

Comment: @Jester: Hmm, you're right.  Executable `.data` happens by default unless you avoid it, so even though the code is in `.data` that's not the cause of the segfault.  So not really a duplicate.  Do we have a Q&A for stray simple label names defined by glibc / CRT letting a program link but then fail at runtime?